# RestKit Foreign Key Connections to-many and to-one

Tags: ios, restkit, foreign-key-relationship

My goal is to implement one-to-many and many-to-one relationship connection with RestKit. I'm using version 0.20pre6.
This page http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html#overview reports half example.
First example is many-to-one.
json:

```
{ "project": 
    { "id": 12345, 
      "name": "My Project",
      "userID": 1
    }
}
```

code:

```
NSEntityDescription *projectEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *userRelationship = [projectEntity relationshipsByName][@"user"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:userRelationship attributes:@{ @"userID": @"userID" }];
```

The thing i missed during my first attempt is that userID needs to be in the Entity too. Otherwise it won't work. I don't really understand why... anyway it works.

My problem is related to the second example which is a one-to-many. Json example:

```
 { "project":
    {   "id": 12345,
        "name": "My Project",
        "userID": 1,
        "teamMemberIDs": [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }
 }
```

code:

```
 NSEntityDescription *projectEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Project" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 NSRelationshipDescription *teamMembers = [projectEntity relationshipsByName][@"teamMembers"]; // To many relationship for the `User` entity
 RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:teamMembers attributes:@{ @"teamMemberIDs": @"userID" }];
```

Now... teamMemberIDs needs to be in the Entity definition just like userID in the previous example. Here are my questions:

1. How do I define teamMemberIDs since it's an array of values?
2. Is there a working example about this things?? The examples directory inside RestKit library only shows nested relationships.
3. Am I doing right? Am I missing something big?

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this exact same problem, but was eventually able to find solution. Hopefully this will help you out.

Using the example:

1. You must have an NSArray property of Project, your NSManagedObject,
   where you can map the teamMemberIDs to. To do this you make a transformable property.
2. Map teamMemberIDs to that property as you would a primitive.
3. Create a connectionDescription just as done in the example.